# Having trouble proving limit points

Tags: general-topology

I have struggled a lot thus far in topology, because of my inability to sort of "prove everything that comes my way". For instance, I just have not been able to prove that points are limit points of sets. For example consider the infinite comb in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ given by $C=\{(x,0)|0 \leq x \leq 1\}\cup \{(\frac{1}{2^{n}},y)|n\in \mathbb{N}, 0\leq y \leq 1 \}$. I know some of the limit points are the whole $y-$ axis. However I continuously am unable to prove this is the case. Let me show my effort, and where I get stumped. I try to use my elementary knowledge in basic analysis to do this, but I always get stuck.

To prove an arbitrary point on the $y-$ axis is a limit point, I try to show that any open ball intersects points in $C$ about every point on the $y-$ axis. Since $\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ converges to $0$, I know there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that if $n \geq N, \frac{1}{2^{n}}< \epsilon$. Now I get stuck with showing an arbitrary open ball,  about a point on the $y-$axis will necessarily intersect points in $C$. Can I just say for every $n \geq N$ there is an $\epsilon_{n}$ such that $B_{\epsilon_{n}}((0,y))\cap (\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},y) \neq \varnothing$? What would be a better way to show this? Also I think about picking an epsilon that depends on $n$. For instance I consider $B_{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}(0,y)$ and try to show this ball intersects a point in $C$ for all $n \geq N$.

So how should I better go about attempting to prove points are limit points of sets? Also how should I attempt to show that these are the only limit points? If someone could give me a full on proof that the $y-$ axis is a set of limit points of $C$, and these points as well as the set $C$ itself are the only limit points, that would be incredibly helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Your logic is mistaken.  The goal isn't to find some open ball that intersects a point in $C$.  The goal is to show that **every** open ball around an arbitrary point on the $y$-axis **must** intersect a point in $C$.  So pick an arbitrary point $p=(0, y_0)$, choose an **arbitrary** ball $B(p, \varepsilon)$ around that point, and prove that the ball must intersect $C$.

Comment: @RobertShore so set a fixed epsilon for the radius of the ball, and since $(\frac{1}{n},y) \rightarrow (0,y)$ there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} <\epsilon$ so that  $B_{\epsilon}((0,y)) \cap C \neq \varnothing$ for all $n\geq N$?

Comment: Now you've got it.